# How to make a library of JPA repositories in a jar file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have several Spring boot projects which use same database. I have made a library of Hibernate entities to share among them. But I faced issues when I tried to include JPA repositories in them since that library doesn't have Spring boot included. Is it possible to do this? How can I add Spring libraries so that it will work?
What entries should I add to build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

An ideal structure would look like this

1. Create the desired library for example package is `com.example`
2. You can then add this library as dependency in any targeted project.
3. Make sure Spring pickups the configuration, entities and classes etc.
4. If your library and targeted application main have same package or its sub-package for example `com.example` in this case we could use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to enable Spring to auto-configure the application context.
5. In another scenario where the root package name is completely different, we would provide our application with the information where these packages could be found. For this purpose, we would use `@EntityScan`.
6. `@EntityScan` annotation is used when entity classes are not placed in the main application package or its sub-packages. In this situation, we would declare the package or list of packages in the main configuration class within `@EntityScan` annotation. This will tell Spring where to find entities used in the application for exam

```
package com.app;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.app") // This will scan all spring beans under com.app package
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.entity") // This will only scan entities under com.entity package
public class SomeApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```